# How to sort by primary table field and pivot in Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Pivot table has one extra field: ordinal for sort order. How can I sort by ordinal and romance_color?

```
Inventory::where('item_id', '=', $itemId)
->with('size')
->orderBy('romance_color')
->get();
```

Documentation has the following example:

```
$users = User::with(array('posts' => function($query)
{
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}))->get();
```

How can I first sort by field in primary table, and then by pivot table field? For example, can I sort by User added date, and then sort by post created date?

Can you suggest alternative solution in eloquent?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used simple join with eloquent:

```
Inventory::where('item_id', '=', '170')
->with('size', 'color', 'item.category')
->join('attribute_value_size_group as gr', 'gr.attribute_value_id', '=', 'size_id')
->orderBy('romance_color')
->orderBy('ordinal')
->select('inventory.*', 'gr.ordinal')
->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Query Builder:

For example:

```
 $pivotTable= DB::table('pivot_table')->where('item_id', $itemID)->orderBy('romance_color')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
$otherModelCollection = Inventory::where('item_id', '=', $itemId)->otherModel()
->orderBy('romance_color')
->orderBy('pivot_ordinal')
->get();
```

It is somewhat related to this.

http://laravel.io/forum/04-17-2014-order-by-pivot-table-attribute-in-eloquent

Comment: This didn't seem to work. I have a many to many relationship with pivot table http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables